# How can I monitor a log file for file size changes with a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, monitor

I am trying to figure out a way to monitor a log file via a script that gets kicked off by task scheduler.

So ideally, what I want to happen, is for the script to check the file size, compare it with the file size of the last time the script ran and if the size has changed write an entry to event viewer and update the oldfilesize.txt file. This would repeat on a daily basis.

So far what I've come up with is this:

```
dir logfile.txt > C:\filesize.txt
//this should give me the filesize and save the result into filesize.txt
COMP oldfilesize filesize.txt
//This should compare the old file created with the new.
```

After those commands is where I get lost. How can I take the results of the `COMP` command and determine if it should save the new results to oldfilesize.txt and write the event in event viewer?

I'm guessing I would use `eventcreate` to trigger the event creation, but I'm not sure how I would do this.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't base this on the output of `dir`, because `comp` will report a difference if *anything* in the output changes (size, date, free disk space, ...). Try something like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set datastore=C:\filesize.txt
set logfile=C:\logfile.txt

if exist %datastore% (
  for /f %%f in ('%datastore%') do set old_size=%%~f
) else (
  set old_size=0
)

for %%f in (%logfile%) do set new_size=%%~zf

if %new_size% neq %old_size% (
  echo %new_size% > %datastore%
  rem do other stuff
)

endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar! That was the exact push I needed.